# Cocos2d v3 group actions like SpriteKit

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

### Desired grouping behaviour

How would I **group** `CCAction` in order to execute them all at the **same time** while knowing when all of the actions in the group are complete?

### Exact SpriteKit equivalent

```
+ (SKAction *)group:(NSArray *)actions
```

### Use case

I want to use this in a board game.

I am moving my game elements around my board with `CCActions`. At the end of all of these animation I would like to a `CCActionCallFunc` as a callback to update game logic and permit user interaction once more.

Ideally I would like to add the *CCActionGroup* and the `CCActionCallFunc`in a `CCActionSequence` and have them execute sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try:

```
CCActionMoveTo *moveTo; // action to group
CCActionScaleBy *scale; // action to group
CCNode *node;

// Init the above actions...

CCActionSpawn *groupAction = [CCActionSpawn actionWithArray:@[moveTo, scale]];
CCActionSequence *sequence = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[groupAction, [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(allDone)]]];
// allDone is your method to run...
[_node runAction:sequence];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since cocos2d doesn't employ any kind of multithreading, you can just fire the actions sequentially:

```
[node runAction:action1];
[node runAction:action2];
[node runAction:action3];
[node runAction:action4];
```

Just add a CCCallBlock to the longest running sequence that runs a block. If all actions run the same length, you would add the call block to the `action4` sequence because that'll finish last.

In Sprite Kit there wouldn't be any guarantee which of action1 through action4 finishes last, in cocos2d there is: the last one to be run will also be the last to finish, assuming they all run for the same duration.

This is when they other actions will also have ended. Alternatively you can create a sequence for each group at the end of each they all run a CCCallBlock that increases a counter, and the last block where the count is equal to the number of grouped actions performs the actual "end of group actions" code.

Comment: Thanks for the info about SpriteKit multithreading vs cocos running everything on one frame. What do you think about using a CCActionSpawn as pointed out by @Jer In Chicago. I find that the example he gave was  more explicit/readable.